# mysql update - skip blank fields?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to know the proper way of doing this.
I have a form where someone can fill in 3 different inputs to update their data.

they can leave one blank if they want and just update the other two or just one. Whatever.

so if i update as:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field1=input AND field2=BLANK AND filed3=input WHERE ID=123);
```

will it leave the blank fields unchanged? just skip over them? or will it replace the field with an empty string/blank field?

If this is the wrong way, what is the correct method?
Thank You!

Comment: Would there be a case that leaving it blank is a desired user update; they want the field to be `''`?

Comment: no, they would never want it to be blank.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will replace them with blank values. The correct way to do it is not to put those items in the query at 
all:

```
if (empty($field1) && empty($field2) && empty($field3) {
  // show error message, nothing to do
  return;
}

$updates = array();
if (!empty($field1))
  $updates[] = 'field1="'.mysql_real_escape_string($field1).'"';
if (!empty($field2))
  $updates[] = 'field2="'.mysql_real_escape_string($field2).'"';
if (!empty($field3))
  $updates[] = 'field3="'.mysql_real_escape_string($field3).'"';
$updates = implode(', ', $updates);

mysql_query("UPDATE table SET $updates WHERE ID=123");
```

Obviously it would be cleaner to put the changes in an associative array or object, and then loop through them.

Comment: Thanks.. I am going with this solution per Dennis's recommendation.

Comment: Something to keep in mind making choices like this... It is almost always the *database* that struggles when a server is brought down by high load. Often your PHP code is sitting around doing almost nothing, while the database chokes and nobody can visit your website. Try to do as much in PHP as possible, keep your MySQL queries simple. Also, it's easy to have one MySQL server and 50 PHP servers, while the opposite is a huge challenge.

Answer (score 5):

The following `UPDATE` statement should leave the fields unchanged if the user uses `''` as their input, otherwise, it will use the input given to update the field.

```
UPDATE table
SET field1 = CASE
                WHEN input = '' THEN field1
                ELSE input
             END
   , field2 = CASE
                WHEN input2 = '' THEN field2
                ELSE input2
             END
   , field3 = CASE
                WHEN input3 = '' THEN field3
                ELSE input3
             END
WHERE ID = 123
```

This is done with the [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) statement.  The `WHEN` conditions check to see what the input it, and if it is `''` (omitted basically) it will use the current value of field1 to update field1 with, basically leaving it unchanged.  If there is a value, it will use that new value instead.

Comment: Why would you burden the database with this task? Why not programmatically do it within php or whatever language you are using to communicate with the db?

Comment: I like how clean this looks. I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: @dennis do you think Adams way is more efficient?

Comment: @DanielHunter I have updated my answer to try to explain how the `CASE` works a little, as well as provided a link to the MySQL documentation for further reading.

Comment: @Daniel Efficient is a vague term, however it is more appropriate. Simply put it this way, you wouldn't ask a cashier to mop up the floor, you would ask a janitor. Sure the cashier could do it but this would only make the people waiting to checkout wait longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to update a certain field you will have to remove the field from your `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE table 
SET field1=input AND filed3=input 
WHERE ID=123
```