# Ignore blank empty fields from update using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help to update mysql. I don't want blank/empty input fields to update but when i keep them blank or empty it automatically updates the fields

here is my code

```
$sql="UPDATE `tblsitesetup` SET
    `site_name` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$sitename_new)."',
    `site_hometitle` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$sitetitle_new)."',
    `site_homedescrp` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$final_description)."',
    `site_homekeywords` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$final_keywords)."',
    `site_analytics` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$final_analytics)."',
    `site_ad1` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$final_ad1)."',
    `site_ad2` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$final_ad2)."',
    `site_ad3` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$final_ad3)."'
    WHERE `site_id` = '1'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: Your friend here should help you : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do it is not to put those items in the query at 
all:

```
$updates = array();
if (!empty($sitename_new))
  $updates[] = 'sitename_new="'.mysql_real_escape_string($sitename_new).'"';
if (!empty($sitetitle_new))
  $updates[] = 'sitetitle_new="'.mysql_real_escape_string($sitetitle_new).'"';
 // .......
 // ....... fill all cases here
$updates = implode(', ', $updates);

$sql = "UPDATE tblsitesetup` SET $updates WHERE `site_id` = '1'";
```

Obviously it would be cleaner to put the changes in an associative array or object, and then loop through them.

Reference: [mysql update - skip blank fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424754/mysql-update-skip-blank-fields)

Answer (score 0):

```
$update=array('site_name'=>$sitename_new
            'site_hometitle' => $sitetitle_new
 /* etc ... */
           'site_ad3' => $final_ad3 );
$sets=array();
foreach($update as $field => $value )
  if( "$value" != "" )
    $sets[]="`$field` = ". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$field);

if($sets) 
{
  $sql="UPDATE `tblsitesetup` SET \n".implode(",\n",$sets)."
    WHERE `site_id` = '1'";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
else
{
  $result=NULL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Build your SQL string using if statements:

$sql = 'UPDATE TABLE SET ';

If (trim($field)!='') $sql.=' FIELD=$field ';

And so on...
Be sure to have a valid SQL statement at the end.